# Is there any way in which to make an Infix function using sourceCpp()

Tags: r, rcpp

I was wondering whether it is possible to make an infix function, e.g. `A %o% B` with Rcpp.

I know that this is possible using the `inline` package, but have yet been able to find a method for doing this when using `sourceCpp()`.

I have made the following infix implementation of `%o%` / `outer()` when arguments are sure to be vectors using `RcppEigen` and `inline`:

```
`%op%` <- cxxfunction(signature(v1="NumericVector",
                                v2="NumericVector"),
                      plugin = "RcppEigen",
                      body = c("
                  NumericVector xx(v1);
                  NumericVector yy(v2);

                  const Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> x(as<Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> >(xx));
                  const Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> y(as<Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> >(yy));

                  Eigen::MatrixXd op = x * y.transpose();
                  return Rcpp::wrap(op);
                           "))
```

This can easily be implemented in to be imported using `sourceCpp()`, however not as an infix function.

My current attempt is as follows:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
#include <RcppEigen.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]



// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix outerProd(NumericVector v1, NumericVector v2) {
  NumericVector xx(v1);
  NumericVector yy(v2);

  const Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> x(as<Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> >(xx));
  const Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> y(as<Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> >(yy));

  Eigen::MatrixXd op = x * y.transpose();
  return Rcpp::wrap(op);
}
```

So to summarize my question.. Is it possible to make an infix function available through `sourceCpp`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to make an infix function available through `sourceCpp`?

**Yes**.

As always, one should read the [`Rcpp` vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html)!
In particular here, if you look in Section 1.6 of [the Rcpp attributes vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf), you'd see you can modify the name of a function using the name parameter for `Rcpp::export`.
For example, we could do:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export(name = `%+%`)]]
Rcpp::NumericVector add(Rcpp::NumericVector x, Rcpp::NumericVector y) {
  return x + y;
}

/*** R
1:3 %+% 4:6
*/
```

Then we'd get:

```r
Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/infix-test.cpp")

> 1:3 %+% 4:6
[1] 5 7 9
```

So, you still have to name C++ functions valid C++ names in the code, but you can export it to R through the name parameter of `Rcpp::export` without having to do anything further on the R side.

Comment: Awesome. I should definitely have gone through those first. Thank you for your response! :)

Comment: Oh, that is a nice one!  Didn't think of that either.  We _can_ hide it from the C++ compiler after all.

Comment: It is in a way really the same as my answer which assign the compile code (from `cppFunction`) to the descired `op`; here it is done via `sourceCpp`. OP originally asked for a function solution (though used package `inline` ...).

Comment: I might not have been clear enough in my post. This was exactly, what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

John Chambers states three principles on page four of the (highly recommended) "Extending R" book:

- Everything that exists in R is an object.
- Everything that happens in R is a function call.
- Interfaces to other software are part of R.

So per point two, you can of course use `sourceCpp()` to create your a compiled function and hang that at any odd infix operator you like.

#### Code Example

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction("std::string cc(std::string a, std::string b) { return a+b; }")
`%+%` <- function(a,b) cc(a,b)

cc("Hello", "World")

"hello" %+% "world"
```

#### Output

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> cppFunction("std::string cc(std::string a, std::string b) { return a+b; }")
R> `%+%` <- function(a,b) cc(a,b)
R> 
R> cc("Hello", "World")
[1] "HelloWorld"
R> 
R> "hello" %+% "world"
[1] "helloworld"
R>
```

#### Summary

Rcpp is really just one cog in the machinery.

#### Edit

It also works with your initial function, with some minor simplification. For

```
`%op%` <- cppFunction("Eigen::MatrixXd op(Eigen::VectorXd x, Eigen::VectorXd y) { Eigen::MatrixXd op = x * y.transpose(); return op; }", depends="RcppEigen")

as.numeric(1:3) %op% as.numeric(3:1)
```

we get

```
R> `%op%` <- cppFunction("Eigen::MatrixXd op(Eigen::VectorXd x, Eigen::VectorXd y) { Eigen::MatrixXd op = x * y.transpose(); return op; }", depends="RcppEigen")
R> as.numeric(1:3) %op% as.numeric(3:1)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    2    1
[2,]    6    4    2
[3,]    9    6    3
R>
```

(modulo some line noise from the compiler).

Comment: Of course this is one way to make it. But what I was wondering is whether it is possible to make the infix function as in the c++ part. 

This would make the code look simething like: `Eigen::MatrixXd * %op%(Eigen::VectorXd x, Eigen::VectorXd y) { Eigen::MatrixXd op = x * y.transpose(); return op;`

Comment: I think you are overlooking where we write C++ and where we write R, and which language syntax is valid where.  And as I tried to explain _it does not matter one iota_ as everything in R is a function call anyway.

Comment: I get that :-) I’m asking more of curiosity than functionality at this point

Comment: I think the simplest answer is _nope_ because the construct does not survice contact with the C++ compiler.